What's the origin and first meanings of the term "grand piano"?
I'm specifically looking for the meaning attached to the adjective "grand" by those who first used it to apply to the earliest musical instrument which is a type of pianoforte where the frame and strings are horizontal (which in turn was a development from the 18th century Fortepiano).
Was the original application of "grand" in this usage implied the sense "large and striking in size, scope, extent, or conception" (Merriam-Webster sense #4) or was it something else?  I doubt that it was merely size since the casing of the earliest non-square pianoforte didn't seem to be larger than a harpsichord.  Similarly, the craftmanship & beauty of the adornment of harpsichords at the time seemed to be as lavish as the first "grand pianos", if lavish was the intended meaning.  Was it perhaps the larger variety of tone production compared to previous fortepiano, larger dynamic range, or larger number of notes (range)?
Maybe an objective answer can be found by tracing the history of early grand piano makers and the names they used.  The name "pianoforte" started in Italy (1700) to name the instrument invented by Venetian harpsichord maker Bartolomeo Cristofori as gravicembalo col piano e forte.  But it seems that further key technological development (before the Steinway era) was in Scotland by John Broadwood and his sons, who even provided the state-of-the-art piano for Haydn to try in London (1791) and that was given to Beethoven in Vienna (1818).
For reference, in the Dutch language they call it vleugel ("wing") which has nothing to do with "grand" while in German it's similar: Flügel.  In French it's Piano à queue ("tail").  In Italian, the modern name is Pianoforti a coda.

The relevant OED definition says Sometimes with defining word indicating size, shape, etc., as grand, square, upright, cottage pianoforte, etc.: Why should English people take their "defining words" from foreigners? For all I know, those Dutch / German / French conventions might have come after the English ones, so you could maybe ask why they didn't copy us.

@FumbleFingers Good point, esp. since the Scot John Broadwood became famous for producing the the early version.  Did he call his piano "grand piano" (for marketing purpose)?.  Or maybe I should have included the Italian term since the design was invented by Cristofori.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americus_Backers , "The term Grand Pianoforte for this design was not coined until Robert Stodart patented and used it to adorn the nameplate of a 1777 model bearing his name as manufacturer". But that article does not have inline citations, so it's not clear where that particular information comes from.

According to the abstract of The English Grand, 1778-1805, by Michael Cole (OUP 1998), "In November 1777 Stodart patented a type of combination grand piano and harpsichord which did not infringe Joseph Merlin’s patent of three years earlier". It seems likely that if an explanation of the use of the word "Grand" is to be found anywhere, it will be in that book.

@ColinFine Would you please post that as an answer? I think it would settle things and forestall closure of the question. Thanks.

It's not an answer, because I haven't seen the book and I don't know whether or not it answers the question.

@GratefulDisciple You realize you can answer your own question, right?

@Robusto  Sure, it's just I need to wait until my downtime (after work).  I have to stop now, but page xi says "In 1772 Americus Backers called his instrument a 'Forte Piano', but Robert Stodart making identical instruments in 1777 coins the term 'grand Piano forte'.  So the rest of the puzzle is why he named it that way, probably in his patent.  This reference shows John Broadwood using the term in 1781 also.

A grand question that strikes a perfect chord with EL&U standards!

Which part of grand is it that you don't understand? ;-)

The term grand for the grand piano was first introduced by Robert Stodart in a patent description in 1777, according to multiple credible sources.  I even found a book that includes the original patent description along with its source. Here is the relevant excerpt from the book The First Fleet Piano: A Musician’s View
by Geoffrey Lancaster:

Two of the first pianos ever seen in England were what we would now refer to as 'grand' pianos. The term 'grand' was first coined in London by Robert Stodart in his 1777 patent for a 'grand Piano-forte'.39 Stodart's patent application describes his

[i]nvention of a new sort of Instrument or of Grand Fortepiano with an Octave Swell and to produce various Tones together or separate and the ... Instrument will be more durable and produce finer and more variable Tones than any yet made.40

Stodart's grand piano was an instrument with up-striking41 hammer action modified to incorporate the plucking action of a harpsichord. It is not known whether Stodart ever made one of these 'grand' combination pianos. Stodart's earliest surviving grand piano without an added harpsichord action is dated 1781.
39    See T. Bingham, Patents for Inventions. Abridgements of Specifications Relating to Music and Musical Instruments A.D.1694-1866* (London: Tony Bingham, The Sign of the Serpent, 1985) [originally published London: George E. Eyre & William Spottiswoode, 1871], p. 12. 
40    c210/18, National Archives, Kew, London. Quoted in M. Latcham, 'Pianos and Harpsichords for their Majesties', in Early Music (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2008), Vol. 36, No. 3 (August), p. 363. 
41    See 'Up-Striking Hammers', in Appendix Q, Volume 2 of this publication.

The invention of the grand piano is attributed to Americus Backers (who was of Dutch descent) in 1772, with the piano action mechanism called 'English Action' or 'English Grand Action'. John Broadwood, together with his then assistant and tuner Robert Stodart helped him to perfect this mechanism. Backers had a workshop where workmen were constructing pianos of different sizes. ‘Grand’ was used to describe the size of the larger pianos constructed which were then called a grand piano, distinguishing them from smaller pianos. Here is the relevant excerpt from the book Music of the past, instruments and imagination : proceedings of the harmoniques International Congress, Lausanne 2004 by Rencontres internationales harmoniques, Michael Latcham:

When Backers died in 1778 an inventory of his effects was made. The inventory has been preserved and offers a glimpse into his workshop.22 There were six workbenches, implying the same number of workmen. Five grand pianos were under construction at the time, their keyboards, soundboards and actions ready to be assembled. There were also 'four small frames for little Forte Pianos' as well as 'two small Piano Forte cases'.23
Backers can be seen as the founder of the English tradition of making grand pianos. His designs were adopted by two important and prolific makers, first Robert Stodart and then, starting in 1785, John Broadwood.
22    The inventory is given in full in Cole, The pianoforte, op., cit., 371-6. 
23     In those days in England the two types of piano, the one in the shape of a harpsichord and the one in the shape of the clavichord, were distinguished by their size: the larger one was called a grand piano and the smaller one a small or little piano. While the term grand piano has since been retained the smaller version is now known as the square piano.

Note: The first piano invented by Bartolomeo Cristofori around the year 1700 is not a "grand piano". It was called clavicembalo col piano e forte ("key harpsichord with soft and loud"), where the Italian term pianoforte, and subsequently, the English word piano come from. The notion of "grand piano" was not present at that time. I've explained how the grand piano came to be. In Italian, the grand piano is called "pianoforte a coda", not just "pianoforte". However, it can also be said that the grand piano as a concept emerged through contributions from multiple inventors, with Backers' mechanism playing a crucial role in giving it its final shape.

Now that we have established the first occurrence of the adjective "grand" applied to pianoforte / fortepiano, what I'm still wondering is the meaning of "grand" that Stodart, Broadwood, and other early users have in mind. I doubt it was size, considering the casing might not be bigger than a harpsichord. Hoping for a clue from these books: The First Fleet Piano: A Musician's View and The Pianoforte in the Classical Era, etc.

Thanks, it might be size after all, which although not bigger than harpsichords, maybe in the consumer's mind it is bigger compared to the majority of fortepiano / pianoforte offering, which was square pianos.  I updated my question accordingly.

@GratefulDisciple You're right, I was focusing on the title when the previous editor did in fact delete the first line of the question I wonder what's the original meaning intended by the first English speaker who added the adjective "grand" to "piano" It was probably an attempt to keep the question as tight as possible.

@Mari-LouA I was partially reversing an edit by ChappoHasn'tForgotten who switched the focus of the Q to "origin" rather than meaning.  I think I was clear from the very beginning that I asked for the meaning of the adjective "grand".  In the commenting process, the origin was quite straightforward, so I retained Chappo's editing in "origin".  Both answers are still valid after my latest edit, so I don't see what's the problem.

@Mari-LouA Yes, he was trying to be helpful.  Thank you for your input as well.

@ermanen Thanks for providing the authoritative citations.  It makes sense that "grand" was used to distinguish from the smaller square pianos.  By that time, they were classified as a different enough instrument from harpsichord that although the physical appearance wasn't more "grand" than harpsichord, it is more "grand" compared to the smaller pianoforte version.

@GratefulDisciple You're welcome! It’s an exemplary question, perfectly suited for EL&U, and I learned a great deal about pianos during my research. Interestingly, I discovered that in 1762, these larger instruments were still referred to as 'pianofortes of large size' until Stodart later patented the term 'grand piano'. The source is The Piano: An Encyclopedia by Robert Palmieri.

@ermanen That additional reference helps bolster the case, as well as this web article mentioning that John Broadwood's trade card was "Harpsichord, Grand & Small Piano Forte Maker".

[Erm...]  the Italian Bartolomeo Cristofori is said to have invented the pianoforte (piano) sometime between 1710-1720. Americus Backers created the pedals to prolong the sound etc. 1772 ... and is most likely the first piano to use pedals rather than knee levers

Cristoferi died in 1731 Wiki says Cristofori continued to make pianos until near the end of his life, continually making improvements in his invention. The grand piano (pianoforte) already existed before 1772. Americus Backers created the pedal system. He improved the instrument, he didn't invent the grand piano. Look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartolomeo_Cristofori#/media/File:Pianoforte_Cristofori_1720.jpg no pedals! But the shape of the instrument is almost identical to a grand piano today.

I suggest you rephrase "The invention of the grand piano is attributed to Americus Backers" it's the pedal system that was invented

@Mari-LouA Yes, What Michael Latcham said in the referenced book is consistent with what I read elsewhere.  He said: "The 1772 piano by Backers is important in that it presents the majority of the distinguishing features consistently found in the English grand pianos made in the subsequent fifty years.  The most important of these, the escapement action apparently devised by Backers, was quickly taken up by Robert Stodart and John Broadwood and was still being built into grand pianos by the Broadwood firm in the 1890s."  So when I read references to "English grand action" it is due to Backers.

Grand, adjective and combining form, has the nuance of "superlative/superior" in some manner.
We have Grand Duke, grand hall, grandstand, grandsire, grand treason, Grand Master, Grand Canyon, etc, etc, ad nausem.
It simply indicates the biggest/best piano.
The fact that foreigners give it another name is no more remarkable than that they have different words for other concepts.

In Italian Granduca, gransala (grand hall), gran maestro , gran canyon etc. etc.  but pianoforte a coda instead of granpiano. And seeing as many instruments and musical terms are derived form Italian i.e. (Eng) piano was loaned from (It) pianoforte this makes it an unusual case,  don't you think? P.S Isn't it high treason?

@Mari-LouA What it is in Italian is of no consequence. No, it isn't "high treason", it is "grand treason" --- the example was chosen as it shows the age of the term "grand" -- c1523 Treason is in two maners that is to say graund treason and petyt treason as it is ordeynyd by the statutz. J. Rastell, Exposiciones Terminorum Legum Anglorum sig. G.ii

I'm sorry to disagree but as I mentioned earlier, words in the field of music and musical instruments were, more often than not, borrowed from Italian. By saying The fact that foreigners give it another name is no more remarkable than that… shows a level of solecism  I did not think you were capable of.

If you wish to believe that the "grand" in "grand piano" differs in some way from the grand in Grand Duke, grand hall, grandstand, grandsire, grand treason, Grand Master, Grand Canyon, etc,, it is entirely a matter for yourself. I would rely on the OED which describes "grand" in this sense as French/ Anglo-Norman and was in use before the grand piano.

@Greybeard Does OED provide a specific meaning of "grand" as applied to "piano"? That's the crux of my question; *what sense transpired in the mind of its first hearers and first speakers when they heard/say "grand piano" (or "grand fortepiano", "grand pianoforte", "Broadwood grand").  As a pianist, I don't usually refer to "size" when marveling at the tonal range of a Steinway grand piano, for example, but "grand" in another sense compared to lesser gp or an upright p.  I also agree that although "piano" originated from Italian, the adjective "grand" should be considered as solely English.

I think that it is the fact that the English give it another name that should occasion a remark. This is for the least, a breach of tradition, or one more such breach rather, which has to have some  explanation; sometimes there is no explanation for this sort of riddle, as there is none for instance, for the English term "cor anglais", which names an instrument  that is neither  English nor  French. (The name first appeared regularly in Italian, German, and Austrian scores from 1749 on, usually in the Italian form corno inglese.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cor_anglais

@LPH Good point.  Brainstorming for considering foreign language equivalents, there are 3 points that came to mind: 1) it seems that the English beat the Europeans in perfecting pianoforte, so as in computer technology, other languages were influenced by the American names of "internet", "browser", etc.; 2) who first used another term or adding an adjective to this particular design of piano (compared to square piano); did "grand" came first or vleugel, for instance; 3) if other languages refer to the physical shape maybe "grand" refers to physical size rather than other attributes.

“If you wish to believe that the "grand" in "grand piano" differs in some way from the grand in Grand Canyon…” No, I thought it was unusual that the Italians called it a coda. I didn't know the term ‘grand piano’ (1777) was patented by a British man but the instrument was invented by  the Italian Cristofori  in 1710-1720 (ca)  which he called Arpicembalo  T Pianoforte was derived from the older fortepiano (loud & soft) while a coda refers to the horizontal strings (corde) of the piano. I didn't know any of this until now.

Curiously I found that the coda is a gran coda if the length of its strings are 260 cm (e andarono affermandosi i "coda" e "gran coda", che all'epoca andavano da 220 a 260 cm) Wikipedia

@Mari-LouA As I begin to study the history of today's classical instruments, I'm struck by the internationalism of the makers, the musicians, the patrons, etc. as well as the progressive enhancement over centuries by international collaborators.  I think there is a porous borrowings of multiple languages as well, as a backdrop of a particular language's development.  "grand" caught early on for English speakers in the early history of piano, but the same instrument variant can easily be named something else by the Italians, French, Dutch, etc. which was then latched in place until today.
